# Why does this equivalent of "on.("click", function) [..]" automatically fires a click even when written in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
var el = $(".threeLines");

el.on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Helps me add the class "active" on a click event to create a nice effect on a menu icon, like this:
[image: How the Effect Should Work, This is the First Code]

I rewritten the code to pure JS as below:

```
function test_xz(s) {
    s.classList.add("active")
}
var el_container = document.getElementsByClassName("threeLines")[0];

el_container.addEventListener("click", test_xz(el_container));
```

But it instantly fires when the document is ready and it completely messes up like this:

[image: The new code messes everything up.]

I understand that `jQuery's "$" corresponds to querySelector`, but I also tried that and it didn't work.

After a bit of research (removing every other function that could be related, logging everything) I concluded that the problematic line is the `addEventListener` itself, I wrote:

```
el_container.addEventListener("click", console.log("Hey!"));
```

and it would just log "Hey!" on page-load.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `test_xz(el_container)` *calls* the `text_xz()` function, passing whatever its return value is to `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: simply because the pure javascript code is **not** equivalent - if you change the jQueery code to `el.on("click", $(el).toggleClass("active"));` then both code snippets will be wrong

Answer (score 5):

In the below line you are calling the method `test_xz` with an argument.

```
el_container.addEventListener("click", test_xz(el_container));
```

Instead, change to the following (without changing the function definition of `test_xz`) :

```
el_container.addEventListener("click", function(){
    test_xz (el_container);
});
```

To toggle the active class:

```
function test_xz(s) {
    s.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

In your question, you mentioned `jQuery's "$" corresponds to querySelector` and I think it's no. `$` is just another name (alias) for `jQuery` and what goes inside the `()` after `$` is a selector.

Comment: Or, better, `el_container.addEventListener("click", test_xz)`, given that a reference to the clicked element is already available within the function via `this` so then the function argument isn't needed.

Comment: Works and I can see why. Unfortuntely, I need it to remove "active" once it's clicked again, how do I go about that?

Comment: @nnnnnn You are correct. I do not want to change the `test_xz` which the OP has written in his post.

Comment: @DanielMoss change `s.classList.add("active")
` to `s.classList.toggle("active")` to toggle the `active` class

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> el_container.addEventListener("click", test_xz(el_container));
> ```

You're *calling* `text_xz()`. That's why the handler is executing. It is for the same reason that passing `console.log("Hey!")` logs that string to the console.

To pass the handler on its own without calling it, simply pass the handler name:

```
el_container.addEventListener("click", test_xz);
```

In addition, you incorrectly ported `toggleClass()` to `classList.add()` and not `classList.toggle()`:

```
function test_xz(s) {
    s.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, but then again, I need the parameter to the function to be there, any ideas?

Comment: Daniel - for this purpose you don't need the parameter, because within the function `this` will refer to the clicked element, so change `text_xz` to work accordingly.

Comment: Correct @nnnnnn, I am trying to pass the el_container (which is just a getCassByName) to that `text_xz` function, tho a way around is to put `el_container.classList.add("active");` in the `text_xz` function itself.

Comment: Within `text_xz` you could say `this.classList.toggle("active")`. You don't need the argument because `this` will already be set to refer to the element (`addEventListener()` does this for you).

Comment: Fixed. Changed to `toggle`, here's my current code: https://pastebin.com/m7L7Jyqd